# How to check if a character is a letter or a number in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript I'm trying to check user entered the alphabet or a number. 
if the user enters "A" it shows **Alphabet** it's ok but if the user enters "1" I want to show **Number** but its show alphabet.
where i done wrong.
Thanks Advance

```
function CHECKCHARATCTER(Letter) {
    if (Letter.length <= 1) {
      if ((64 < Letter.charCodeAt(0) < 91) || (96 < Letter.charCodeAt(0) < 123)) {
        return "Alphabhate";
      }
      else if (47 < Letter.charCodeAt(0) < 58) {
        return "NUMBER";
      }
      else { return "Its NOt a NUMBER or Alphabets"; }
    }
    else { return ("Please enter the single character"); }
}
a = prompt("enter the number or Alphabhate");
alert(typeof (a));
b = CHECKCHARATCTER(a);
alert(b);
```

Comment: You can't do `a < b < c`, you need `a < b && b < c` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here:

```
if (64 < Letter.charCodeAt(0) < 91) //...
```

JS isn't Python. You can't simply do `a < b < c`, you need to explicitly use the logical && operator: `(a < b) && (b < c)`.

Comment: Just a heads up as to what is happening when you do `64<Letter.charCodeAt(0)<91` it will evaluate `64<Letter.charCodeAt(0)` which is false (aka 0) and then it will use that result. `0 < 91` which is true.

Answer (score 1):

```
You can use regular expressions. Please have a look at regular expressions. It will be very helpful.
function checkAlphaNum(char) {
    let alphaReg = new RegExp(/^[a-z]/i);
    let numReg = new RegExp(/^[0-9]/);
    if(alphaReg.test(char)) {
        return "ALPHABET";
    } else if(numReg.test(char)) {
        return "NUMBER";
    } else {
        return "OTHER";
    }
}

console.log("Output : ", checkAlphaNum('A'));
console.log("Output : ", checkAlphaNum(1));
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified you conditions as it's shown in the following code. Also you can check it out [here](https://jsfiddle.net/8d4qbfah/)

```
function CHECKCHARATCTER(Letter){
    if (Letter.length <= 1)
    {
        if (Letter.toUpperCase() != Letter.toLowerCase()) { 
            return "Alphabet";
        }
        else if (!isNaN( Letter)) {
            return "Number";
        } else{ 
            return "Its Not a Number or Alphabet";
        }
    }
    else { 
        return("Please enter the single character");
    }
}
input = prompt("enter the Number or Alphabet");
output = CHECKCHARATCTER(input);
alert(output);
```

Comment: This will fail for letters that don't have upper and lower case variants.